# Can I legally change my name to "Darth Misogynus", or would I get sued by Disney?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, trademark, name

Obviously, Darth comes from Star Wars, which is currently owned by Disney. Misogynus is an expression of my ideological beliefs. If I legally change my name to "Darth Misogynus", will I get sued by Disney? Can I use the name "Darth Misogynus" in business if I have legally changed my name to it? I live in the US.

Comment: This asks two differnt questions.

Comment: It really asks at least 3 questions: (1) Can I legally change my name to include "Darth" which is some sort of trade name of Disney? (2) Can I legally change my name to include the potentially offensive "Misogynus"? (3) Can I use the name "Darth" in business bearing in mind Disney's interests in the name? I can't see any problem in using "Misogynus" in business but maybe it would contravene some rule too.

Answer (score 2):

### [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

No. You can not take a proper name or be named by your parents with a name that is made up of fantasy words, or which is insulting on itself. As such, you can't use "Darth" as a name part, and "Misogynus" is also not allowable as a name.

You are not free to change your name at all after you have been named. Only [**important reasons**](https://www.bmi.bund.de/DE/themen/moderne-verwaltung/verwaltungsrecht/namensrecht/namensrecht-node.html) allow to apply for a change of name (Namensänderung), and the new name needs to comply with the rules when naming a child. It is an exception to be allowed to change the name, and only to remove problems the old name imposes. Merely "i dislike my old name" or "that other name is cooler" is not an important reason under the law.

The best you might get is this as an artisan's name in addition to your normal name.

Comment: Good news for some Germans: You can now exchange the order of your given names. They still don’t allow Russians with gendered last names to fix an incorrect name.

Comment: Artist or stage name, not artisan, I believe. This would also cover names in religious orders. I wonder if the Jedism movement could affect this ...